Launchpad API to search/list all ubuntu package
Is there a way to get a list of all ubuntu packages available in archive.ubuntu.com through Launchpad API. I have to programmatically get that in java. So i can't use the python launchpadlib client.
As per the document i think following endpoint should have worked but it returns "null"
https://api.launchpad.net/devel/archives?ws.op=getByReference&reference=ubuntu/bionic
Please help!

What version of Ubuntu are you trying to get the data for?

I tried for focal jammy bionic all of them returned null. I would like to be able to get list for last 5 releases.

I doubt you can when a release is EOL they stop offering the data.

I am unable to get it even for lunar.
Also, I can get the list from apt commands by doing a wildcard search. Shouldn't APIs also support it

Lunar is Ubuntu 23.04 it is EOL you just proved my point.

Tried for "noble" same error :( i feel like i have got the API Call wrong maybe.
Assuming API doesn't work to get list of packages, what other possible methods could there be that i can put in my java prorgam. TIA
